# Reload linechart only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this chart element

```html
<canvas class="main-chart" id="line-chart" height="200" width="600"></canvas>
```

and i have this script to insert the data

```js
<script>
        
            function hour(){
             
            return a=["00:00","01:00","02:00","03:00","04:00","05:00","06:00","07:00","08:00","09:00","10:00",
                "11:00","12:00","13:00","14:00","15:00","16:00","17:00","18:00",
                "19:00","20:00","21:00","22:00","23:00"];
         };
         
        var data_visitors_present=<?php echo json_encode(visitorsPresentDay()[0]);?>;
        var data_visitors_previous=<?php echo json_encode(visitorPreviousDay()[0]);?>;
 var lineChartData = {
   labels : hour(),
   datasets : [
    {
     label: "My First dataset",
     fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
     strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
     pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
     pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
     pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
     pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
     data : data_visitors_previous
    },
    {
     label: "My Second dataset",
     fillColor : "rgba(48, 164, 255, 0.2)",
     strokeColor : "rgba(48, 164, 255, 1)",
     pointColor : "rgba(48, 164, 255, 1)",
     pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
     pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
     pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(48, 164, 255, 1)",
     data : data_visitors_present
    }
   ]

  }
    
        </script>
```

The final result is this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EI0e.png)

I want every 10 seconds to reload only the chart element;
I wrote this without effect..

```js
<script>
        var chart=document.getElementById('#line-chart');
        setInterval(chart){(
            function hour(){
             
            return a=["00:00","01:00","02:00","03:00","04:00","05:00","06:00","07:00","08:00","09:00","10:00",
                "11:00","12:00","13:00","14:00","15:00","16:00","17:00","18:00",
                "19:00","20:00","21:00","22:00","23:00"];
         };
         
        var data_visitors_present=<?php echo json_encode(visitorsPresentDay()[0]);?>;
        var data_visitors_previous=<?php echo json_encode(visitorPreviousDay()[0]);?>;
 var lineChartData = {
   labels : hour(),
   datasets : [
    {
     label: "My First dataset",
     fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
     strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
     pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
     pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
     pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
     pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
     data : data_visitors_previous
    },
    {
     label: "My Second dataset",
     fillColor : "rgba(48, 164, 255, 0.2)",
     strokeColor : "rgba(48, 164, 255, 1)",
     pointColor : "rgba(48, 164, 255, 1)",
     pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
     pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
     pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(48, 164, 255, 1)",
     data : data_visitors_present
    }
   ]

  }
            }1000);
        </script>
```

how i can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is something strange about the way you are trying to call `setInterval`. The first argument should be a function, which you are not doing. (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Try changing to the following inside your script tags:

```
function hour(){
     return a=["00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", "05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00","14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00"];
};

setInterval(function() {
    var chart=document.getElementById('#line-chart');
    var data_visitors_present=<?php echo json_encode(visitorsPresentDay()[0]);?>;
    var data_visitors_previous=<?php echo json_encode(visitorPreviousDay()[0]);?>;
    var lineChartData = {
        labels : hour(),
        datasets : [
            {
                label: "My First dataset",
                fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data : data_visitors_previous
            },
            {
                label: "My Second dataset",
                fillColor : "rgba(48, 164, 255, 0.2)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(48, 164, 255, 1)",
                pointColor : "rgba(48, 164, 255, 1)",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(48, 164, 255, 1)",
                data : data_visitors_present
            }
        ]

    }
},1000);
```

If you want the data to actually change, you will also need to change the way you are loading the data from php. One possible suggestion is to create a php page that runs your php functions (`visitorsPresentData()` and `visitorPreviousDay()`) and echos to the screen, then retrieve that result via ajax within the `setInterval` function.

It also does not appear to me that you are actually writing the `lineChartData` to the chart anywhere? Could be an error in that code as well.

Comment: It doesn't work like that. Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Comment: It disappearιng the chart for some reason.

Comment: Where are you writing `lineChartData` to the chart?